# SQL in ASP.Net core 2.0 dont work because i get an error with update-database in console

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

**update-database give this error:**

PM> update-database

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
>         User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\henri\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
>         Entity Framework Core 2.1.1-rtm-30846 initialized 'SimpleImageGalleryDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
>   System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'mutipleactiveresultsets'.
>      at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.b__0(DateTime giveUp)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)

Keyword not supported: 'mutipleactiveresultsets'.

**My appsettings.json:**

```
{
   "ConnectionStrings": 
   {
       "DefaultConnection":"Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=SimpleImageGallery;Trusted_Connection=True;MutipleActiveResultSets=true;"
   },
   "Logging": 
   {
       "IncludeScopes":false,
       "LogLevel": 
       {
           "Default":"Warning"
       }
   }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<Data.SimpleImageGalleryDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've misspelled `multiple` as `mutiple`.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) . It was very stupid ;)

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue using `EF core 2.2 / SQLExpress`.

The cause of the problem is the provider setting in connection string:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=LENOVOTOUCH\sqlExpress;
Integrated Security=SSPI;
Initial Catalog=XXX
```

The solution is to remove the Provider setting.